# Mongoid, how to keep relations in sync for common parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid3

I have three models:

```
Agency
has_many :owners
has_many :properties

Owner
belongs_to :agency
has_many :properties

Property
belongs_to :owner
belongs_to :agency
```

The `agency.properties` relation should refer to all properties that all owners have, but when I create a property inside an owner, the `agency.properties` relation is not created. I want this relation to be automatically fulfilled, as well as deleted when the owner or the property is deleted.

How can I achieve this behavior with mongoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a pretty specific use case, there is no way to 'automatically' do this using mongoid 'out of the box'. What I would suggest you is to have some before_save hooks, that would guarantee the state of your relations. You also, depending of your use case, Property could be a denormalized(embedded) object inside Owner and Agency.

Comment: Okay. Do you think there will be a relevant performance issue the way I'm doing it?

Comment: Yes, if you have big collections, having to keep in sync those has_many would impact on writes. Also remember that Mongodb dont have atomic transactions across multiple collections, so you could have inconsistent data.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write something like:

```
Agency
has_many :owners

Owner
belongs_to :agency
has_many :properties

Property
belongs_to :owner
```

And then add an instance method in your Agency model:

```
def properties
 owners.map(&:properties).flatten.uniq
end
```

However, this approach will query your database to retrieve the owners and then will query your DB again once per each owner to retrieve each owner's properties.

Hope this could help.

**EDIT**

There is another solution which implies just 2 queries:

```
def properties
 Property.where({:owner_id.in => owner_ids})
end
```

**PROS**:

It uses only two queries.

It returns a Mongoid Criteria (the previous solution returned an array). Thus you can chain scopes and so on ( i.e. my_agency.properties.sold #if you have defined a sold scope)

**CONS**:

This code seems less readable.

Additionally it's less maintainable. If you change the foreign key in the Owner-Property relation you should update this method (Property.where({:foreign_key...}) or you change the way an owner has many properties. The first option is still valid as long as each owner properties can be found with the instance method some_owner.properties.

Comment: this is gorgeous indeed, but introduces a n+1 issue.

Comment: @JúlioTurollaRibeiro. I think we should first ask:

 "how many owners might an agency have? ten or ten thousands? And how fast would that query be?"
Then: "is there a true relation between agencies and properties? or agencies has properties just because they have owners which in turn have properties?" As your application grows, how easy/difficult will it be to keep all relations synchronized??

Comment: @JúlioTurollaRibeiro. I've edited the answer with a just-2-queries solution; but it introduces some other issues regarding code maintenance. Regards